# Rename Lightning Component Bundles via AuraDefinitionBundle gets an 'unexpected error'

Tags: lightning-aura-components

There is a helpful article on an easy way to rename lightning component bundles: https://www.codescience.com/blog/2017/how-to-rename-lightning-component-bundles

Essentially you query and edit the DeveloperName of AuraDefitionBundle directly.

However, when I tried this today, I got an error on saving:  `[object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 624622357-2036 (444998763)`

Can anyone confirm whether this method is no loner working, or if the error is specific to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method used to work when the blogpost was written .I am working with internal team to update this blogpost and you are right now the approach highlighted does not work any more .

You are right that this no longer works and only alternative is to use the  resource and use the label to override for admin purposes

```
<design:component label="Your label">
```

If you need to change the names then you will have to use an IDE to change names and push via metadata API .You will have to delete the previous components via destructive xml since that will still exist in the org .